# Bounds and Frame, If a view is Not rotated, is the size of these two property always identical to each other?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to make a view(not rotated) wider in a controller. I tried two approaches to do that:

1. MyView.frame.size.width += 80
2. MyView.bounds.size.width += 80

And I noticed that they gave me different effect, how does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs on the bounds and frame of a `UIView` respectively...

[`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds):

> Changing the bounds size grows or shrinks the view relative to its center point.

[`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame):

> Setting this property changes the point specified by the center property and the size in the bounds rectangle accordingly.

Therefore increasing the *bounds* width by 80 will add 40pts to the left and right sides of the view, whereas increasing the *frame* width by 80 will add 80pts to the right hand side of the view.

While you are correct in saying that when the `transform` is identity, then `bounds.size` should be the same as `frame.size`, this doesn't mean that the behaviour when you *set* these values is the same (which it isn't). I would also take note of [what Duncan says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363251/2976878) about the namings of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

If the transformation matrix is the identity matrix (not just not rotated) then I would expect frame.size and bounds.size to be the same and changing either to have the same effect.

Note that the code you posted won't work in Objective-C. You'd have to write it like this:

```
CGRect myViewFrame = myView.frame;
myViewFrame.size.width *=2;
myView.frame = myViewFrame;
```

(also note that I'm following iOS naming conventions and naming myView starting with a lower-case letter. Variables should start with lower-case letters.)

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Doc:

**When you set the size value of frame:**

> When you set the frame property, the size value in the bounds property
>   changes to match the new size of the frame rectangle.

**When you set the size value of bounds:**

> When you set the size of the bounds property, the size value in the
>   frame property changes to match the new size of the bounds rectangle.

So the size of frame and bounds should retain same. However, different effect is possible(like different position) as `frame` refer to **superView's coordinate system** but bounds specifies the size of the view (and its content origin) in the view’s **own local coordinate system**.

**Notice: sometimes frame will be considered invalid**

> If a view’s transform property is not the identity transform, the
>   value of that view’s frame property is undefined and must be ignored.
>   When applying transforms to a view, you must use the view’s bounds and
>   center properties to get the size and position of the view. The frame
>   rectangles of any subviews are still valid because they are relative
>   to the view’s bounds.